# Permission denied for ngork and no direct link created

Tags: linux, ngrok, termux

I ran script shaclick by

```
bash shaclick.sh
```

but when ngork start it is showing

```
"chmod: changing permissions of 'ngrok': Operation not permitted"
```

and no direct link created.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you refer to this script :

[shaclick.sh](https://github.com/SharqanAhamed/shaclick/blob/master/shaclick.sh)

The problem is the user your're executing the script with does not have the right to change permissions on the file/directory.

Only the owner (or the root user) can change permissions on a file/directory. Is your user the owner ? Use `ls -l` to check. The third field is the file/directory owner.